# Read an array to its (length minus one)position

Tags: android, loops

I want to read a `JSONArray` till its second last position. How can I do that? I almost tried everything but no result till now.

My `JSON`,

```
[{
    "subject_name": "Sociology-I",
    "total_classes": "1",
    "total_attended": "1",
    "percentage": "100"
}, {
    "subject_name": "English-I",
    "total_classes": "37",
    "total_attended": "36",
    "percentage": "97.297297297297"
}, {
    "subject_name": "Hindi -I",
    "total_classes": "1",
    "total_attended": "1",
    "percentage": "100"
}, {
    "subject_name": "",
    "total_classes": "3",
    "total_attended": "3",
    "percentage": "100"
}, {
    "subject_name": "Economics II",
    "total_classes": "1",
    "total_attended": "1",
    "percentage": "100"
}, {
    "subject_name": "History-I",
    "total_classes": "1",
    "total_attended": "0",
    "percentage": "0"
}, {
    "total_percentage": "95.454545454545"
}]
```

Now when I use

```
for (int i = 0; i <jsonArray.length(); i++)  {
    JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
}
```

It is giving me Last object also i.e "total_percentage".. I tried

```
    i< jsonArray.length()-1
```

also, but didn't worked for me.. What to do If i don't want "total_percentage". I need only till second last element or object

Comment: Forget about solution, your JSON is not structured properly. If you are interested in structuring your JSON into a better model, I can post an answer for that.

Comment: Is it not possible to read this array till its second last position??

Comment: It is definitely possible. But why to have a work around when you can have proper solution

Answer (score 1):

Ideally your JSON should be like

```
{
    "marks":[{
        "subject_name": "Sociology-I",
        "total_classes": "1",
        "total_attended": "1",
        "percentage": "100"
        },{
        "subject_name": "Sociology-I",
        "total_classes": "1",
         "total_attended": "1",
        "percentage": "100"
        }
    ],
    "total_percentage":98.4
}
```

then

```
JSONArray marks = response.optJSONArray("marks");
//then iterate through marks
//here response is your actual modified JSON
```

JSONs are meant to structure your data according to Categories, so its a bad model to have total marks object in individual marks array.

**EDIT- Quick Fix solution for your problem - 1**

```
int length = jsonArray.length() - 1;
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)  {
    JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
}
```

**Quick Fix solution for your problem - 2**

```
for (int i = 0; i <jsonArray.length(); i++)  {
    Object marksObject = jsonArray.opt(i);
    if(marksObject instanceof JSONObject){
         JSONObject mark = (JSONObject) marksObject;
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay I will do it like this, but can u please help me this time.. already +1 givento you

Comment: I posted two alternates for you.

Comment: Quick Fix no  1: Its not working.. After this I am not getting any data.. BLANK SCREEN

Comment: Can you upload the code that you are actually trying. I see many answers suggesting the same and this solution giving you blank screen is little out of understanding. Please provide us your actual code for us to debug.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
for (int i = 0; i <jsonArray.length() - 1; i++)  {
JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);}
```

Comment: Its not working.. After this I am not getting any data.. BLANK SCREEN

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope it will help you.

```
for (int i = 0; i <jsonArray.length(); i++)  {
    JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    jsonObject1.remove("total_percentage");
}
```

Comment: Didn't work at all. Same situation found " ListView with 7 elements"